# How can I develop a 0-100 composite or index score using multiple Z scores from multiple independent variables?

Tags: python, pandas, statistics

I'm really interested in index scores like the [human development index](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Human_Development_Index) or [economic freedom index](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Index_of_Economic_Freedom) where they rank things on a 0-100 scale based off of a bunch of different variables (e.g. press freedom, property rights, etc). I would like to do this with z-scores for multiple columns in a Python notebook.

I'm able to calculate the Z scores just fine using scipy:

```
from scipy.stats import zscore
no_income_data_important_columns_only.apply(zscore)
```

and get something like:[image] I understand these z-scores are telling me how high or low the values are relative to the average. But now I want to be able to understand how high or low each row is **across** all of the measurements/columns...

I don't really know what to do with all the Z-scores in order to calculate an index or composite score (on a 0 to 100 scale). Do I multiply them or add them together or do something else to aggregate them?

Comment: You cant aggregate z-scores, unless they are calculated from the same standard deviation and mean. Z=(x-mean)/std

Comment: ...but you seem to have the raw data? So can't you calculate a z-score across the columns? (Using all the data)

Comment: You can certainly aggregate z-scores, that's almost the entire purpose of using them to form a composite. The fact that they are dimensionless further allows you to compare things across various dimensions (i.e. combining price and durability of an item into a single overall measure of "Quality")

Comment: Since this is a discussion question, it's off topic for SO, which is for specific programming problems. Try stats.stackexchange.com instead. That said, what seems like the obvious generalization of (x - mean)/s.d. to multiple dimensions is something like Z = sqrt(transpose(X - mean) . Sigma^-1 . (X - mean)) where X is a column vector and Sigma is the covariance matrix. Note that Z^2 is the term that appears in the multivariate Gaussian density function, analogously to z^2 in the one-dimensional Gaussian. There is probably a name for Z as it's shown here, although I don't know without looking.

Answer (score 1):

This still has the fatal conceptual flaw from your earlier posting.  However, you have now described the problem clear enough to address the issue.

The Z-scores are merely a tool to normalize your data: getting the various ranges and deviations onto a similar scale for ease of the *real* processing steps.  It does *nothing* to solve your central problem: what is important?

Every such "index" is merely the opinion of a research team as to what is important, how features interact, etc.  Your post essentially asks us to blindly determine what is important to the people who read your index report.  This is obviously not going to work.

*You* have to determine how you intend to weight these items.  Note that your Z-score is simply a linear scale for each feature.  Does this correlate *linearly* with someone's gut feeling of freedom?  If one entity controls and censors all media outlets, does that reduce the effect of other factors?  How does 100% property freedom and no press freedom compare to 50% freedom of each?

Until you decide how these factors affect each other, and how they correlate to your readers' feelings, you are not organized well enough to solve the problem you've posed.
You're trying to reduce a multi-dimensional survey to a linear metric.  To have a reusable algorithm, you must first have a reproducible context [paraphrase of Ralph E. Johnson, in "Design Patterns"].  This is not a reproducible context, and you haven't yet researched your particular use case.

Comment: If I did have a sense for how to weight them, how would I then aggregate them?

Comment: You're still in a circular question: the aggregation method is merely the functional implementation of your aggregation scheme.  If you decide that they're independent variables and represent "gut feeling" in roughly linear fashion, then your aggregation function is a simple linear equation, where the coefficients are the linear weights to the factors.

Comment: What if I wanted to build an aggregate z-score but I wanted to weight variable A 50%, variable B 30%, and variable C 20%, how might I do this?

Comment: You would do it with exactly that linear equation.

Comment: I don't get it but oh well. I'll try again

Comment: I'm unclear on where you're unclear.  You just described to me a linear equation in three variables, with the coefficient for each.  I don't see where you're stuck.